# How to find objects by terms

Tags: php, query, taxonomy, search, terms

I am struggling with a search filtering. Firstly, my script is searching for users using natural search SQL. The query returns ids of users. Now I would like to filter them by terms which are assigned to each user. I used this:

```
 $terms_ids = array();
 $terms_ids = $_GET['user_sport'];
 $objects = get_objects_in_term($terms_ids, 'user_sport');
 $unique = array_unique($objects);
 print_r($unique);
```

But this **get_objects_in_term** function returns every object which has at least one term. What I want to achieve is the opposite thing. If one user has  football as a term and does not have basketball he should not be displayed when I filter users with football and basketball. Only if I use football. Is there any way of solving this problem? Another approach would be second SQL query but I found out terms and taxonomies relations a bit weird just to write SQL query.

Comment: All `get_objects_in_term ` does after cleaning up its parameters is run this query and return the results: `$object_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT tr.object_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ($taxonomies) AND tt.term_id IN ($term_ids) ORDER BY tr.object_id $order");` So you wouldn't be too wide of the mark in using your own query.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "users" you are trying to pull is a custom post type. You can use "tax_query" as below.

```
$user_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'custom_user_post',  // Custom post type,
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'paged'             => ( ! empty( get_query_var( 'paged' ) )? get_query_var('paged'): 1 ),
    'tax_query'         => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy'      => 'user_sports', //assuming your custom taxonomy is 'user_sport'
                'field'         =>  'slug',
                'terms'         =>  array( 'football' )
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy'      => 'user_sports', //assuming your custom taxonomy is 'user_sport'
                'field'         =>  'slug',
                'terms'         =>  array( 'basketball' )
            )
    )
);

$users_list = new WP_Query( $user_args );
```